# Why this code wont work? XML with .StartsWith

Tags: c#, xml, windows-phone-7, linq-to-xml

Why this work like this:

```
        XDocument dataFeed = XDocument.Parse(e.Result);
        var guide = from query in dataFeed.Descendants("MaxPayne3")
                                    select new NewGamesClass
                                    {
                                        GameID = (string)query.Element("ID"),
                                        GameTitle = (string)query.Element("Title"),
                                        GameDescription = (string)query.Element("Description"),
                                        GameGuide = (string)query.Element("Guide")
                                    };

        if (NavigationContext.QueryString.TryGetValue("selectedItem", out selectedIndex))
        {
            if (selectedIndex == "0")
                GuidesListBox.ItemsSource = guide.Where(ngc => ngc.GameTitle.StartsWith("Feel"));
            else if (selectedIndex == "1")
                GuidesListBox.ItemsSource = guide.Where(ngc => ngc.GameTitle.StartsWith("Serious"));
```

But not like this:

```
            if (selectedIndex == "0")
                GuidesListBox.ItemsSource = guide.Where(ngc => ngc.GameID.StartsWith("000"));
            else if (selectedIndex == "1")
                GuidesListBox.ItemsSource = guide.Where(ngc => ngc.GameID.StartsWith("001"));
```

i want to use the GameID Instead The GameTitle.

Sorry about no XML, too early in the morning for me, lol

Here:
https://dl.dropbox.com/u/27136243/AchivementHunters/XML/GameList.xml

Here is the Class:

```
public class NewGamesClass
{
    string gameID;
    string gameTitle;
    string gamedescription;
    string gameImage;
    string gameGuide;
    string videoLink;
    public string GameID
    { get { return gameID; } set { gameID = value; } }
    public string GameTitle
    { get { return gameTitle; } set { gameTitle = value; } }
    public string GameDescription
    { get { return gamedescription; } set { gamedescription = value; } }
    public string GameImage
    { get { return gameImage; } set { gameImage = value; } }
    public string GameGuide
    { get { return gameGuide; } set { gameGuide = value; } }
    public string VideoLink
    { get { return videoLink; } set { videoLink = value; } }
}
```

Comment: You haven't said in what way it doesn't work.

Comment: GameID = (string)query.Element("ID"), - it's string

Comment: i get a NullReferenceException. sorry agoing, im still drinking my morning cofee.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most of the `<MaxPayne3>` nodes do not have a child `<ID>` node, hence this code:

```
select new NewGamesClass
           {
               GameID = (string)query.Element("ID"),
               GameTitle = (string)query.Element("Title"),
               GameDescription = (string)query.Element("Description"),
               GameGuide = (string)query.Element("Guide")
            }
```

will produce mostly nulls for `GameID`. Then this code:

```
guide.Where(ngc => ngc.GameID.StartsWith("000"))
```

will throw `NullReferenceException` for all those elements

change it to this:

```
guide.Where(ngc => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(ngc.GameID) && ngc.GameID.StartsWith("000"))
```

and it should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Given that we have no data, the only significant difference here is the `.GameTitle.` vs `.GameID.`. I'm assuming that "won't work" here means "it throws an exception". The primary exception I can predict there would be `NullReferenceException`, because `.GameID` is `null`, so `.GameID.anything` is illegal.

Which makes me think that `<ID>whatever</ID>` doesn't exist at the location you think it does (which will result in `.GameID` being a `null` reference). Things to verify:

- that it exists there
- that the case is correct (`ID`, `Id`, `id`, etc)
- that is is an *element*, not an *attribute*
- that it isn't in a namespace

Update: and here's the problem from the data:

```
<MaxPayne3>
  <Title>Part I Complete - 20G</Title>
  <Description>Complete Part I Of The Story</Description>
  <Guide>Story related, cannot be missed.</Guide>
  <Image>http://www.xbox360achievements.org/images/achievements/925/-K6lMA==.jpg</Image>
  <VideoLink/>
</MaxPayne3>
```

which has no `<ID>`. There are a lot more like this. So: you need to handle that. A pragmatic check would be:

```
...blah...guide.Where(ngc => ngc.GameID != null && ngc.GameID.StartsWith("000"));
```

Comment: yeah, i get a NullReferenceException, but eveything seems correct.

Comment: @Twenty40 press f5... I have already explained that. There are lots of records with no ID / GameID